# Mass 301 redirect -- which is the best way? htaccess or httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We need to redirect up to 300 old pages to new pages like the following example

/ext-player/bbc-radio-ext-player /bbc-radio
/ext-player/radio-one /radio-one

is htaccess entry or httpd.conf entry which is apt one to do this?

I heard that the htaccess file is accessed on every request whereas httpd.conf file accessed only once so a bigger htaccess file may impact site's speed. is it true?

Comment: You've heard right. Using `httpd.conf` is a much better method to doing this. The issue most people face is they don't have access to it, so they turn to `.htaccess`. If you have access, 100% go that route.

Comment: @Joe is correct, and here is the more detailed (and official) explanation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when